# WordPress search only works on other pages only work in home page

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on my own Avada Theme, only my WordPress homepage search working. other pages search not working I have attached all codes  Any idea how to solve the issue? I have attached my search code.

Searchform.php

```html
<?php
/**
 * The search-form template.
 *
 * @package Avada
 * @subpackage Templates
 */

// Do not allow directly accessing this file.
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit( 'Direct script access denied.' );
}
?>
<form role="search" class="searchform" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url();?>"
 <div class="search-table">
  <div class="search-field">
   <input type="text" value="" name="s" class="s" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'Search ...', 'Avada' ); ?>" required aria-required="true" aria-label="<?php esc_html_e( 'Search ...', 'Avada' ); ?>"/>
  </div>
  <div class="search-button">
   <input type="submit" class="searchsubmit" value="&#xf002;" alt="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'Avada' ); ?>" />
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you be more precise on "not working"? Is there an error message? are the results empty? do you get redirected to the wrong page?

Comment: yes i am getting 404 your can check my website : https://www.enrichclinic.com.au/

Comment: try `action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) ?>`  Also, you are not closing the opening of <form at the end of the line.

Comment: hello stender I have tried this code not woking for me

Comment: on every page i looked at, the result was `action="#"`, i have no idea why loading for example the page "about" shows a 404 error when you give a get parameter called `s`, some other pages like "dermatology" actually shows nothing when given the parameter. So the problem seems to be the home url display. Did you try `echo get_home_url();`?

Comment: Hello, Kaddath I have tried echo get_home_url(); but getting same error

Comment: can you try to replace `<?php echo home_url();?>` by the actual adress of the root of your site, to confirm that this is the cause of the problem?

Comment: i have tried not working for me  i have noticed if i search https://www.enrichclinic.com.au/blog/ "dermatology" this page going to https://www.enrichclinic.com.au/blog/?s=dermatology# how can make url URL : https://www.enrichclinic.com.au/?s=dermatology# after search then i hope it will resolve can you help me the same